# wp editor add trailing "\" to urls in database when used in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin and on one of my pages i wanted to use wp editor so i inserted wp editor like this (following codex examples)

```
    <?php
    $settings = array(
    'wpautop' => false,
    'textarea_rows' => 5,
    'tinymce' => array( 'plugins' => 'wordpress' )
        );
    $content = $item['sponsor'];
    $editor_id = 'sponsor';
    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
    ?>
```

but problem is when i use wp editor to add some links like

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/myurlid"><img src="http://myimagepath" /></a>
```

wordpress writes that in database but adds trailing slashes to urls like this

```
    <a href=\"http://facebook.com/myurlid\"><img src=\"http://myimagepath\" /></a>
```

Why does it do that? and any solutions to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, before submitting a content to database use stripslashes

```
stripslashes($_POST['sponsor']);
```